# Null Pointer exception While getting object of manyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I had two tables Stock and StockLocation. In that Each Stock has multiple StockLocation and each StockLocation had single Stock.

when I had fetching stock from StockLocation than I was getting Null Pointer Exception

```
 @Entity(name = "stock")
 public class Stock {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="stock")
   @JsonManagedReference
   private List<StockLocation> stockLocations;
 }

 @Entity(name = "stock_location")
 public class StockLocation {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
   @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id")
   @JsonBackReference
   private Stock stock;
}
```

Now when I was trying to getting Stock from StockLocation It would give Null Pointer Exception.

```
StockLocation sl = stockLocRep.findById(id).get();
sl.getStock();
```

Comment: You don't need fetch type eager for many to one because that what it is by default `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`. You probably didn't save the relationship properly so the stock id is probably null. Check the database or your code.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NPE? What object is NULL? And are you getting two different or just one NPE? Please clarify.

Comment: which line is throwing NPE? Because sl.getStock(); should not throw NPE as fetch type is EAGER (which will cause Stock to be loaded using JOIN in same query)